# Is it possible to use Voicemod API or Morphvox API with Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, voice

I'm a french student in game programming and I'm trying to find a way to apply filter/voice changer on the mic.

I'm making an multiplayer online video game with Unity, players in a game can talk to each other (using Vivox) and i would like to apply a voice changer to a player at some moments in the game (for immersion purposes).
I found online that Voicemod has an API but I can't find any information regarding this. (I'm don't know if Morphvox even has an API)

So, is there a way to change players voices directly via Unity C# scripts with any of those too apps?

I'm sorry in advance for any possible english mistakes and thanks in advance!